# Spring webflux read body as a jackson JsonNode?

Tags: spring, jackson, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Is it possible to read a JSON body into a Mono ?

I have something like the following

```
public void myHandler(ServerRequest request) {
    request.bodyToMono(JsonNode.class);
}
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it's possible, at runtime it maps to an ObjectNode.

```
public void myHandler(ServerRequest request) {
    request.bodyToMono(ObjectNode.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert it to a `JsonNode`, you can just have an intermediate step to do the conversion:

```
// Autowire in the ObjectMapper using your desired method
private ObjectMapper mapper;

public Mono<ServerResponse> myHandler(ServerRequest request) {
    Mono<JsonNode> nodeMono = request.bodyToMono(String.class)
        // Wire in your ObjectMapper
        .map(mapper::readTree);
    // Do something with Mono and return a ServerResponse
}
```